# for-loops in python (basic)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, continue

Is it possible to make a two functions with seperate for-loops but that the second function gets what the first one did? I have a very simple example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

def func():
    for i in a:
        if i == 1:
            continue

def func2():
        func()
        for i in a:
            print(i)

print(func2())
```

The problem with the second function is that it doesnt "get" what the first function does. How could I fix this? I want the second function to get the first one so that I can continue on with statements.

Comment: can you save the results of the first loop into a list?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get'?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Can you explain what output you're trying to get?

Comment: What exactly did the first function *do* that you expect to be visible to the caller?

Answer (score 2):

To pass information from one function to another, the first function needs to `return` it.

```
def func(a):
    r = []
    for i in a:
        if i == 1:
            continue
        r.append(i)
    return r

def func2(a):
    r = func(a)
    for i in r:
        print(i)

func2([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: FWIW, you can rewrite `func` as a comprehension: `return [i for i in a if i != 1]`